# Yearly population projections for the fifty American states till 2050

Tags: us-census, population, north-america

I'm looking for population projections for the fifty American states (yearly up till 2050). Are these available online, or in any academic papers? Thanks.

I've found the following two sources; the first only gives values for 2010/2020/2030/2040; the second source gives projections which are slightly outdated (from 2004), and these go up till 2030.

[National Population Projections - Cooper Center](http://demographics.coopercenter.org/national-population-projections/)
[Population Projections - CDC WONDER](https://wonder.cdc.gov/population-projections.html)

Answer (score 5):

US Census has [population projections through 2060](https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popproj/data/datasets.html), and is also the data behind both of the sources you already found.

[State population projections](https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popproj/guidance.html) (except for Vermont) list from the Census.

Not sure about data quality here; I only clicked on Virginia and District of Columbia, and Virginia's link had succumbed to linkrot. Updated reference:
[Virginia's Population Projections](http://demographics.coopercenter.org/virginia-population-projections/)

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for population projections for the fifty states (as opposed to national population projections from your link). I can't find that data on the US Census Bureau - do you know if it's available?

Comment: my bad...updated answer